# Swiftui CoreData one to many relationship

Tags: core-data, relationship, one-to-many

For example two models Person and Car. Person has many cars. My question is how to add car to already created Person. If I tray in AddNewCarView:

```
var person: Person
```

...

```
var newCar = Car(context: viewContext)   
newCar.name = name   
newCar.model = model   
And now, what...?    
newCar.person = person (gives newCar to all persons)   
Or.   
person.addToCars(newCar)
```

Is that something I have to add in predicate? In Car I have:

```
    static func fetchCars() -> NSFetchRequest<Car> {   
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Car> = Car.fetchRequest()   
    reqest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "", ) ..?    
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Car.timestamp, ascending: true)]   
    return request   
  }
```

Comment: Fetch the person not the car. That way you only see the person’s cars. You will have to filter it if you fetch the car

Comment: `newCar.person = person`, this is correct. If it isn’t working for you then you haven’t set up the relationship correctly. Check that you have not created a many-to-many relationship

Comment: I fetched persons in the main list but I want to tap on the person's name to navigate to list of person cars and add car.

Comment: In Person relationship -> cars -> Car -> person -> To Many.  In Car  relationship person -> Person -> cars -> To One.

Comment: Your relationship setup looks good but I am at convinced the code I referenced in my previous comment is correct so the issue must be with something not included in this question. Like how the code above is being called or something

Comment: @Joakim In ContentView I have `@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Person.fetchAll)
  var persons: FetchedResults<Person>` then in ForEach I get each person and in NavigationLink destination CarView in which I have `var person: Person` like above in my question. That is about all of the simple code that is not working.